# How can I get a post with all related ones?

Tags: laravel, join, relation

Here is my table structures:

```
// tickets
+----+------------+----------------------+--------+---------+
| id |  subject   |        content       | closed | user_id |
+----+------------+----------------------+--------+---------+
| 1  | subject1   | question1            | 0      | 123     |
+----+------------+----------------------+--------+---------+

// answers
+----+----------------------+---------+-----------+
| id |        content       | user_id | ticket_id |
+----+----------------------+---------+-----------+
| 1  | answer1              | 123     | 1         |
| 2  | answer2              | 456     | 1         |
+----+----------------------+---------+-----------+
```

Now I need to get a ticket with along all its answers. I can do that using pure SQL like this:

```
SELECT t.*, a.*
FROM tickets t
LEFT JOIN answers a
ON t.id = a.ticket_id
WHERE t.id = ?
```

---

Now I'm using Laravel and I want to do that using `with()` class *(however not sure it is possible)*. Any idea what change should I make in the models for doing that?

Noted that I can get just a ticket in Laravel like this:

```
$ticket = Tickets::where('id', $request->id)->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make a [hasMany()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relationship in your `Tickets` model class.

```
public function answers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Answers::class, 'ticket_id', 'id');
}
```

And then in your controller query

```
$tickets = Tickets::with('answers')->where('id', $request->id)->get();
```

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. Also I guess there is another approach (except `with()`). Do you have any idea what's that? *(to assign answers into another variable)*

Comment: this is quite good, right? I didn't even bother to look for other solution.

Comment: I think he's talking about this: `$ticket = Tickets->where('id', $request->id); $answers = $ticket->answers;`

Comment: it will require additional `n+1` query